# how can I move a string date to a new component with 3 fields

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a component called DateComponent, and it contains 3 inputs (year/month/day). I also have a component which contains a formGroup and has a formControlname date which is like yyyy-mm-dd.

If I want to go through the FormGroup path, how can I get the data from DateComponent nicely as yyyy-mm-dd to the form in parent component?

I tried to use ControlValueAccessor, but the problem is I have 3 ngmodel (day, month, year) in DateComponent while in parent there is one which is Date.

I really prefer not to break down my formControl from date to 3 fields. Any thoughts or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we make a custom form control extending [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) the important part is when we define registerOnChange and when "something" change we call to the function.

A simple .html

```
<input [ngModel]="year" (ngModelChange)="year=+$event;change()">
<input [ngModel]="month" (ngModelChange)="month=+$event;change()">
<input [ngModel]="day" (ngModelChange)="day=+$event;change()">
```

See that each change in an input call to the function "change()"

The important part:

```
  year:number;
  month:number;
  day:number;
  constructor() { }

  onChange:any; //<--define a function OnChange

  //here we give value to our function "onChange"
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  //each change of the inputs
  change(){
    if (this.year && this.month && this.day)
    {
      const date=new Date(this.year,this.month-1,this.day)
      this.onChange(date); //<--we call to the function onChange
                           //we pass as argument the value we want to get our
                           //control
    }

   //the writeValue is executed onTime at first with the value
   //of the control
   writeValue(value: any[]|any): void {
    this.year=value?value.getFullYear():null;
    this.month=value?value.getMonth()+1:null;
    this.day=value?value.getDate():null;
  }
```

**Update** to not fight with GTM replace the functions as

```
writeValue(value: any[] | any): void {
    if (value) {
      const date=new Date(Date.UTC(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth(), value.getDate()));
      this.year = value.getFullYear();
      this.month = value.getMonth() + 1;
      this.day = value.getDate();
      this.change()
    }
  }

  change() {
    if (this.year && this.month && this.day) {
      const date = new Date(Date.UTC(this.year, this.month - 1, this.day));
      this.onChange(date);
    }
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uc183z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate%2Fdate.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo - I have done almost the same thing except using ngModelChange. Now my problem here is from the parent I have a <div [formGroup]="form><my-date formControlName="fullDate"></my-date></div>. I expected to see the value, but nothing has been added. Any thoughts on that

Comment: @ArashEM, The "key" is the function writeValue, check if you get any value (using `console.log(value)`. I've write a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uc183z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). NOTE: "fullDate" is a Date object, not a string

Comment: thanks @Eloseo - it works now. I missed the providers.

Answer (score 0):

you can maybe do something like this

```
let date = 10
let month = 1
let year = 2019

let finalDate = new Date()
finalDate = new Date(finalDate.setDate(date))
finalDate = new Date(finalDate.setMonth(month))
finalDate = new Date(finalDate.setFullYear(year))
console.log(finalDate)
```

the final output would be something like this

```
2019-02-10T04:47:37.886Z
```

if you want to remove the time you can do that using datepipe

```
console.log(this.datePipe.transform(finalDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

the output of above console.log would you be

```
2019-02-10
```